# How to attach a file to send a mail using php

Tags: php, file-upload, virus

I have been struggling to get a mail with attachment using php . 
The below is my **application form.php**

```
<form name="frm" action="ThankYou.php" method="post" style="padding-top:10px;">
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%; color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;"
rules="all" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>*mandatory fields</td>
</tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" valign="top"><p><table id="Table2"  cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="3" width="100%" align="center"
                                            border="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="WIDTH: 152px; HEIGHT: 31px" vAlign="top" align="left"><span id="Label1" class="text" class="text" style="background-color:Transparent;"><span style="font-size:13px; font-family:Arial; font-weight: normal;
color:#000000"><span id="Label15" class="asterix" style="color:Red;"></span>Form 
              of address</span></span></td>
                                                <td style="HEIGHT: 31px"><select name="DDtitle" id="DDtitle" class="formtext">
    <option value=" ">Select</option>
    <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
    <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
    <option value="Ms.">Mrs.</option>

</select></td>
                                            </tr><br>
                                            <tr>
        <td height="35" valign="top"><span style="font-size:13px; font-family:Arial; font-weight: normal;
color:#000000"><font color="#FF0000"><sup>*</sup></font>First Name:<font color="#FF0000"></font></span></td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" size="35" name="name" id="name" value=""></td></tr>
                                            <tr>
        <td height="35" valign="top"><span style="font-size:13px; font-family:Arial; font-weight: normal;
color:#000000"><font color="#FF0000"><sup>*</sup></font>Last Name:<font color="#FF0000"></font></span></td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" size="35" name="lname" id="lname" value=""></td></tr>
                                            <tr>
    <td height="35" valign="top"><span style="font-size:13px; font-family:Arial; font-weight: normal;
color:#000000">Address: <font color="#FF0000"></font></span></td>
                        <td valign="top"><textarea cols="28" rows="2" name="address"  id="address"></textarea><br><br>
        <span id="txt_mobile" style="font-size:11px;"></span></td>
    </tr>
                                        <tr>
        <td height="35" valign="top"><span style="font-size:13px; font-family:Arial; font-weight: normal;
color:#000000"><font color="#FF0000"><sup>*</sup></font>City:<font color="#FF0000"></font></span></td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" size="35" name="city" id="city" value=""></td></tr>

    <tr>
        <td height="35" valign="top"><span style="font-size:13px; font-family:Arial; font-weight: normal;
color:#000000"><font color="#FF0000"><sup>*</sup></font>Contact No:<font color="#FF0000"></font></span></td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" size="35" name="number" id="number" value=""></td></tr>
                                                <tr>
        <td height="35" valign="top"><span style="font-size:13px; font-family:Arial; font-weight: normal;
color:#000000"><font color="#FF0000"><sup>*</sup></font>Email Id:<font color="#FF0000"></font></span></td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" size="35" name="email" id="email" value=""></td></tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td height="35" valign="top"><span style="font-size:13px; font-family:Arial; font-weight: normal;
color:#000000"><font color="#FF0000"><sup>*</sup></font>Position Applied for:<font color="#FF0000"></font></span></td>
                                                <td style="HEIGHT: 21px"><select name="position" id="position" class="formtext">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Trainee Business Development Executive">Trainee Business Development Executive</option>
    <option value="Business Development Executive">Business Development Executive</option>
    </select>

</td></tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="WIDTH: 152px" vAlign="top"><span id="Label4" class="text" class="text"> 
              <span style="font-size:13px; font-family:Arial; font-weight: normal;
color:#000000">Current organisation</span></span></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" size="35" name="organization" id="organization" value=""></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="WIDTH: 152px; HEIGHT: 43px" vAlign="top"><span id="Label5" class="text" class="text"> 
              <span style="font-size:13px; font-family:Arial; font-weight: normal;
color:#000000">Designation</span></span></td>
                                                <td style="HEIGHT: 43px"><input type="text" size="35" name="designation" id="designation" value=""></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="WIDTH: 152px; HEIGHT: 23px" vAlign="top"><span lang="EN-GB" style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 11pt; mso-fareast-font-family: 'Times New Roman'; mso-ansi-language: EN-GB; mso-fareast-language: EN-US; mso-bidi-language: AR-SA"><span id="Label32" class="text" class="text"><span style="font-size:13px; font-family:Arial; font-weight: normal;
color:#000000">Total 
              work experience </span></span></span></td>
                                                <td><select name="ExperienceYears" id="ExperienceYears" class="formtext">
    <option value=" ">Years</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
    <option value="32">32</option>
    <option value="33">33</option>
    <option value="34">34</option>
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
    <option value="37">37</option>
    <option value="38">38</option>
    <option value="39">39</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>

</select><select name="ExperienceYears" id="ExperienceMonths" class="formtext">
    <option value=" ">Months</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    </select></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td vAlign="top" width="100%" colSpan="2">
                                                    <table id="Table11" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="1" width="100%" border="0">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class="text" style="HEIGHT: 15px" vAlign="top"><span style="font-size:13px; font-family:Arial; font-weight: normal;
color:#000000">Resume</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                            </td>

                                                            <td vAlign="top"><input name="file" type="file" id="file" class="FormText" />
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <!--<tr>
                                                <td colSpan="2"><span id="Label13" class="text">Enter the text as it is shown in the box below</span></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colSpan="2"><img id="Image1" src="../CreateCaptcha.aspx" style="border-width:0px;" /><input name="strCAPTCHA" type="text" maxlength="6" id="strCAPTCHA" class="formtext" style="width:112px;" /></td>
                                            </tr>!-->
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" colSpan="2"><input style="margin-left:50px;" type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" onclick="return reguser_validation(frm);"/></td>
                                            </tr>
        <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
                                        </table>
                                                        </TR>
                                                    </TABLE>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
<tbody>
</table>



</td>
</tr></td></tr></table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>



</table>
</td>
</tr>
/*Validations*/
<script type="text/javascript" src="email_validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="signup.js"></script>
            <script language="javascript">
function reguser_validation(field) 
            {   
                var name = document.frm.name;
                var lname = document.frm.lname;
                var city = document.frm.city;
                var number = document.frm.number;
                var email = document.frm.email;
                var position = document.frm.position;

    if ((name.value == null) || (name.value == ''))
                {
                    alert("Please enter your First name");     
                    name.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                /*if(name='!alphabetics')
                {
                    alert("Please enter Alphabets in your First name"); 
                    return false;
                }*/
if ((lname.value == null) || (lname.value == ''))
                {
                    alert("Please enter your Last name");     
                    lname.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                /*if(lname='!alphabetics')
                {
                    alert("Please enter Alphabets in your Last name"); 
                    return false;
                }*/
if ((city.value == null) || (city.value == ''))
                {
                    alert("Please enter your City name");     
                    city.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                /*  if(city='!alphabetics')
                {
                    alert("Please enter Alphabets in your city name"); 
                    return false;
                }*/
if ((number.value == null) || (number.value == ''))
                {
                    alert("Please enter your Contact Number");     
                    number.focus();
                    return false;
                }
if(Mobile_Validate(number) == false)
                {
                    return false;
                }

            if ((email.value == null) || (email.value == '')){
                    alert("Please enter your Email ID.");
                    email.focus();
                    return false;
                }

                if (emailcheck(email.value) == false){
                    alert("Please Enter Valid Email ID.");
                    email.focus();
                    return false;
                }


                if (position.value ==  '')
                {                   
                    alert('Please Enter the position that your applying for');
                    position.focus();
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
            </script>
```

The below is my **ThankYou.php**

```
<?php

$to = "web@adisysonline.com";
$subject = "Uploaded file";

$fileatt = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileatt_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$fileatt_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$headers = "From: $from";

if (is_uploaded_file($fileatt)) 
{
    // Read the file to be attached ('rb' = read binary)
    $file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
    $data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
    $mail_body = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $mail_body . "\n\n";
    $data = chunk_split( base64_encode($data));
    $mail_body .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" . " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" . "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . 
    " filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}--\n"; 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
        $msg .= ucfirst ($key) ." : ". $value . "\n"; 
    }
}
else {
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { 
        $msg .= ucfirst ($key) ." : ". $value . "\n"; 
    }
}



    $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $msg, $mail_body, $headers);

    if($ok)
        echo "<b>Thank you for submitting Your Resume.<br> We will get back to you as soon as possible.</b>";
    else
        echo "Server Busy please try after few minutes";

    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

and i also need to know how to add virus checker for the attachment to avoid any virus
Any help would be appreciable..waiting for expertise reply....

Comment: It took me < 1 minute to find this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220815/sending-a-simple-attached-file-via-php-mail-function

Comment: A word of advice: Use the freely available library like PHPMailer to ease up the task

Answer (score 3):

```
$file1=$_FILES['filenm']['name'];
$to = "example@gmail.com";
                    $subject = "your subject";
                    $base = basename($file1);
$file = fopen('your folder name/'.$file1,'rb');
$size = filesize('your folder name/'.$file1);
$data = fread($file,$size);
fclose($file);
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message="<html><body>";
$message="<table border='1'>";
$message.="<tr><td colspan='3' align='center' style='color:#FFFFFF;font-size:large; background:#000000'>Information</td></tr>";
$message.="</table>";
$message.="</body></html>";
//boundary
$div = "==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(time())."x";
//headers
$head = "From: $email\n".
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n".
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n".
    " boundary=\"$div\"";
//message
$mess = "--$div\n".
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n".
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n".
    "$message\n\n".
    "--$div\n".
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$base\"\n".
    "Content-Description: $base\n".
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n".
    " filename=\"$base\"; size=$size;\n".
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n".
    "$data\n\n".
    "--$div\n";
$return = "-f$email";
mail($to,$subject,$mess,$head,$return);
```

try it code with change your email, your subject, your message, and your folder name